# Flutter web, disable focus on button on Tab press

Tags: flutter, button, flutter-layout, focus, flutter-web

I have a Textfield then a Button then a Textfield.
On Tab key press focus goes to first Textfield, on Tab key press again focus goes to the button. How can I ignore focus on button and give focus to second Textfield when Tab key is pressed 2 times?

Answer (score 10):

A better solution would be to wrap the widget, that you don't want to be focusable in a `Focus` widget and set the properties `descendantsAreFocusable` and `canRequestFocus` to `false`. Like this:

```
Focus(
  descendantsAreFocusable: false,
  canRequestFocus: false,
  child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('CLICK ME')),
),
```

That way the widget will automatically be skipped when pressing Tab

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that combines `onEditingComplete` and `RawKeyboardListener`.

`onEditingComplete` is used to catch `ENTER` key while `RawKeyboardListener` is used for the `TAB` key

[image]

```
class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firstFieldFocusNode = useFocusNode();
    final secondFieldFocusNode = useFocusNode();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            RawKeyboardListener(
              focusNode: firstFieldFocusNode,
              onKey: (event) {
                if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.tab) {
                  secondFieldFocusNode.requestFocus();
                }
              },
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'First field'),
                onEditingComplete: () {
                  print('ICI');
                  secondFieldFocusNode.requestFocus();
                },
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 48.0),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('CLICK ME')),
            const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
            TextFormField(
              focusNode: secondFieldFocusNode,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Second field'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`secondFieldFocusNode.requestFocus()` inside `onKey` didn't work but this code does:

```
class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firstFieldFocusNode = FocusNode();
    final secondFieldFocusNode = FocusNode();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            RawKeyboardListener(
              focusNode: firstFieldFocusNode,
              onKey: (event) {
                if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.tab) {
                  firstFieldFocusNode.nextFocus(); <============= HERE
                }
              },
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'First field'),
                onEditingComplete: () {
                  print('ICI');
                  secondFieldFocusNode.requestFocus();
                },
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 48.0),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('CLICK ME')),
            const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
            TextFormField(
              focusNode: secondFieldFocusNode,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Second field'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I just replaced `secondFieldFocusNode.requestFocus();` by `firstFieldFocusNode.nextFocus();`

Thank you Thierry for your help

Comment: Is there any widget that allows me to ignore the widget from tab focus @woshitom

Comment: as handling multiple focus nodes becomes cumbersome.